# How to fix space between FrameLayout - ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement my layout but I can't obtain the correct layout.
When my device is in Portrait mode and I use the constraint.Guideline, I try to find the correct number to put the ORANGE FrameLayout bottom near the BottomNavigationView.
If I use **app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".90"** is near the "correct" number, but I think is not right way...also when I put the device in Landscape Mode the ORANGE FrameLayout desappear and for re-appear I have to set **app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".80"**. I'm newbie

[image: portrait]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorMain"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The activity_nav_drawer drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/master_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
        <!--app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav"-->
        <!--app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer" />-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_nav.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.masterdetailexample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_bottomnav_drawer" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_mail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.masterdetailexample.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_nav">


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_90"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".80" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/bgDetail">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/total_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/bgBottomTotal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline_90">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="grey">#BBBBBB</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="blue">#03A9F4</color>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#7b4bff</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#6539ba</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="bgBottomNavigation">#fe485a</color>
    <color name="bgBottomTotal">#fe885a</color>
    <color name="bgDetail">#999999</color>
    <color name="colorMain">#7b4bff</color>
    <color name="windowBackground">#fdfdfd</color>
</resources>
```

when I rotate the device il Landscape mode, I have the same problem above plus another problem with **BottomNavigationView**, I would like to delete the white space to the left and to the right (or replace with the same color of the BottomNavigationView)

Comment: Please find your solution in [your revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53897929/revisions) and post it as an answer of its own.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what I have to do..with my answer

Comment: 1. Take your solution from the revision history ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8a26e883-990c-4138-8e96-949eb4568460/view-source)) and 2. publish it by posting it as an Answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hnjo.png

Answer (score 0):

Found the SOLUTION:
I'm trying to implement my layout but I can't obtain the correct layout.
When my device is in Portrait mode and I use the constraint.Guideline, I try to find the correct number to put the ORANGE FrameLayout bottom near the BottomNavigationView.
If I use **app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".90"** is near the "correct" number, but I think is not right way...also when I put the device in Landscape Mode the ORANGE FrameLayout desappear and for re-appear I have to set **app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".80"**. I'm newbie

[image: portrait]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorMain"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The activity_nav_drawer drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/master_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
        <!--app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav"-->
        <!--app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer" />-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**!!! EDIT TO SOLVE the problem**

**app_bar_nav.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.masterdetailexample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constrain_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/bgDetail"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constrain_container"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/total_fragment_container">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/total_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@color/bgBottomTotal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation">

        </FrameLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_bottomnav_drawer" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**!!EDIT  now not used!!**
**content_mail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.masterdetailexample.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_nav">


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_90"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".80" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/bgDetail">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/total_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/bgBottomTotal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline_90">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="grey">#BBBBBB</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="blue">#03A9F4</color>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#7b4bff</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#6539ba</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="bgBottomNavigation">#fe485a</color>
    <color name="bgBottomTotal">#fe885a</color>
    <color name="bgDetail">#999999</color>
    <color name="colorMain">#7b4bff</color>
    <color name="windowBackground">#fdfdfd</color>
</resources>
```

when I rotate the device il Landscape mode, I have the same problem above plus another problem with **BottomNavigationView**, I would like to delete the white space to the left and to the right (or replace with the same color of the BottomNavigationView)